# Stop double click action on a action-column

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I've a grid panel in extJS 4.1.1. With other columns I've an actioncolumn(xtype:'actioncolumn'). I include a handler with that column. When I click it , it works fine and open a new window with many things loading. But I got error when I double click on that column. Advance welcome for any help.......

```
{
        text            : 'Signature',
        menuDisabled    : true,
        sortable        : false,
        id              : 'signature',
        xtype           : 'actioncolumn',            
        width           : 60,            
        items           : [{
            icon        : "${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'ADD01003.png')}",
            tooltip     : 'Add Signature',
            scope       : this,
            handler     : function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var records = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).data,
                  fullName    = records.fullName,
                  nickName    = records.nickName,
                  salutation  = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).raw.m00i012001.name,
                  searchValue = records.id ;

                  var filters    = new Array();
                  var store =Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('S02X004001');
                  store.clearFilter(); 
                  filters.push({property:'member', value:searchValue});
                  store.loadPage(1, {
                      filters  : filters,
                      callback : function(records, options, success) {
                      var view = Ext.widget('v02x004001');
                      view.show();
                      Ext.getCmp('fullName-sv02x00400104').setValue(fullName);
                      Ext.getCmp('nickName-sv02x00400104').setValue(nickName);                      
                      Ext.getCmp('member-sv02x00400104').setValue(searchValue);
                      Ext.getCmp('salutation-sv02x00400104').setValue(salutation);
                      }
                  });
            }
        }]
    }
```

Comment: please post also your error

Answer (score 0):

Not to resurrect any Zombies, but for anyone having the same Problem in ExtJS 4, 5 or 6 this workaround should work (maybe the Classnames need to be slightly modified, pasted Code is proven to work in 5.1.1).

The trick is to not modify the actioncolumn but to fix the itemdblclick event handler one might have like so:

```
listeners:
{
    itemdblclick: function(v, record, item, index, e)
    {
        var flyTarget = Ext.fly(e.target);
        if(flyTarget.hasCls('x-action-col-icon') || flyTarget.hasCls('x-grid-cell-inner-action-col'))
        {
            e.stopEvent();
            return;
        }
        //your code here
    }
}
```